# How to achieve url re-writing in front of Amazon S3

Tags: url-rewriting, amazon-s3, url-routing

I'm building an entirely static site (just HTML/JS) that's using [Firebase](http://firebase.com) as the data store. I'd like to use url rewriting to make the URLs look half decent; a request for `/app/app-slug` should load the `app.html` page, but keep the url in the browser the same. The javascript then reads the url and pulls down the appropriate data from Firebase.

This is easy enough with an apache server & .htaccess, but I'd like to use Amazon S3 to store and deliver the entire site (I'm expecting a reasonable amount of traffic at some point in the future). I've scoured the web and am sure there's no way to achieve this with only S3, but **I'm wondering if there's any other service or method that can achieve this (seemingly) simple task?** I'd rather not have to worry about firing up an EC2 instance just to rewrite the URLs.

Thanks in advance for any solutions.

Comment: Ever figure this out?  I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @user1626384 Nope, I ended up forking out for a VPS and running the site from Nginx instead.